# What are minimal paths, generators of graph ideal in a cyclic graph $C_n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graph-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

> *Minimal cuts are the generators of the cut ideal while the Alexander duality of path ideal generated by the minimal paths is the cut ideal -- more on Graph ideals [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410107.pdf). Graph ideals are special case of Stanley-Reisner ideal that is explained in Sturmfels Combinatorial Commutative Algebra book.*

---

Consider a cyclic graph such as $C_3$ or $C_4$. What are their minimal paths that specify their corresponding graph ideal?

**What are the minimal cuts of $C_n$?**

*P.s. The computation of graph ideals and cut ideals [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244119/how-to-compute-graph-ideal-or-cut-ideal-of-a-graph).*

Comment: This questio is very terse. Please include some context.

Comment: @quid Graph ideals are special case of Stanley-Reisner ideals, more in Sturmfels CCA book or in [thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410107.pdf) on graph ideals.

Comment: Thanks for expanding the question. I changed my votes.